# Oracle database Listener error

Tags: database, oracle, listener

Actually my connection in sql developer was fine while working yesterday. Today I cannot connect and when I checked the status of my listener(LISTENER1), it had, somehow, been terminated. When I tried to start it I got this error message:

```
TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is C:\app\neiral\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Log messages written to c:\app\neiral\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-BNNHGQO\listener1\alert\log.xml
Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.78)(PORT=2521)))
TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   64-bit Windows Error: 49: Unknown error
```

This also happened another time. However, I was able to 'fix' it with a simple computer restart. Now it persists. My other listener (the one created at database creation I think) is started without problems (its name is LISTENER, however it does not appear in the NET Configuration Assistant. Could they be messing up with each other and because they listen on different ports I cannot connect?), while the listener (LISTENER1) with which I created my connections cannot start and gives the aforementioned error.

This is the 'listener.ora' file

```
LISTENER1 =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.78)(PORT = 2521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC2521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER1 =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\neiral\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\neiral\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER1 = C:\app\neiral
```

This is the 'tnsnames.ora' file

```
LISTENER_RLLESHI =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.78)(PORT = 2521))


REJNALD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.78)(PORT = 2521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = rejnald.lleshi)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC2521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Thanks for taking the time to think about this.

Comment: Sure that `192.168.0.78` is the server IP address?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496097/listener-lsnrctl-start-tns-00515-connect-failed-because-target-host-or-object-d